# realloc seems to not be reallocating memory

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, realloc

I need to dynamically append a char to a string, so I'm using `realloc()` to add more memory as I need it.

I'm new to C (coming from Python) so I've been reading a lot and this was the best I could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void append_to(char *array, char value) {
    size_t buffer = (strlen(array) * sizeof(char)) + sizeof(char);
    char *new_array = realloc(array, buffer);
    if (new_array == NULL) {
        printf("CRITICAL ERROR\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    array = new_array;
    int position = strlen(array);
    array[position] = value;
}

int main() {
    char *list = malloc(sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++){
        append_to(list, 'a');
        printf("%d -> %s\n", i, list);
    }
}
```

This is just an example to showcase the issue. The code runs flawlessly until iteration 24, see below:

```
1 -> a
2 -> aa
[...] //omitted
23 -> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
24 -> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
25 ->
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you forget to add another NUL char at the end of your c-string.

Second, realloc may change the memory location of the data, but you passed the `list` as value, so the relocation is not visible in the case of data relocation.

That should lokks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void append_to(char **array, char value) { // pass pointer's address
    size_t buffer = (strlen(*array) * sizeof(char)) + sizeof(char) + sizeof(char); // one more to tackle the end of the string
    char *new_array = realloc(*array, buffer);
    if (new_array == NULL) {
        printf("CRITICAL ERROR\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    *array = new_array;
    int position = strlen(*array);
    (*array)[position] = value;
    (*array)[position+1] = 0; // end of string
}

int main() {
    char *list = malloc(sizeof(char));
    list[0] = 0; // end of string
    for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++){
        append_to(&list, 'a'); // pass address of array so that it can be changed by the call
        printf("%d -> %s\n", i, list);
    }
    free(list); // always explicitly free unused resources
}
```

Comment: That works, I didn't know about the NUL char at the end of a string. I might need to read more about pointers and memory location too, thank you!

Comment: Minor: Unclear why code uses `int position = strlen(*array); (*array)[position] = value;` versus the more efficient and type correct `(*array)[buffer] = value;`.  Perhaps an echo of OP's code?

Comment: @chux I don't like to modify too much the original code, of course you're right! Think need for an edit?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Its a minor thing. Only a big enough issue to note.

Comment: @chux Won't `buffer` return the end position for the `array`? If I add the value to the last position, I'll have one unused space + no space for the NUL, I guess. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yes, `(*array)[buffer] = value;` is not correct.  Yet rather than call `strlen()` a second time (which costs O(buffer)), `(*array)[buffer-2]  = value; (*array)[buffer-1] = '\0';`.   This also avoids using `int` where `size_t` is called for - of course this lst point only needed very long strings.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't receive `array` as a double pointer, so you can't reassign the caller's pointer when `realloc` has to move the allocation.

To fix,

```
// Receive double pointer
void append_to(char **array, char value) {
    // Add dereferencing as needed
    size_t buffer = (strlen(*array) + 2) * sizeof(char);
    char *new_array = realloc(*array, buffer);
    if (new_array == NULL) {
        printf("CRITICAL ERROR\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    *array = new_array;
    int position = strlen(*array);
    array[0][position] = value;
    array[0][position+1] = '\0'; // Explicitly NUL terminate, don't assume new memory is zeroed
}

int main() {
    char *list = malloc(sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++){
        append_to(&list, 'a');  // Pass address of list
        printf("%d -> %s\n", i, list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works if I add one extra char for the NUL terminate, so I'll pick Jean's as the correct answer. Thank you for the explanation though!